# jQuery form plugin: field value serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, escaping

I'm used to send passing data with the jQuery form pluging using `data: $("form#myform").serialize()`. It doesn't make sense to create separate forms in my current case, since there are only two fields. Hence I created the following function:

```
function storeNotificationMessage(name) {
    var content = $("textarea#" + name).val();
    var id = $('#id').val();

    content = encodeURI(content); // tried this
    content = escape(content);    // and that

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        data: "entry=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&msg=" + msg,
        type: 'post',
        url: '?url=updateEntry',
        success: function(response) {
            done();
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately neither `encodeURI` nor `escape` work correctly for special characters like ' or + or  German umlauts.

**Question**: what is the proper way to encode text values?

Comment: IIRC, if you post `data` as an associative array, jQuery should take care of escaping the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `escape` nor `encodeURI` nor `+` when dealing with urls. Simply leave all encoding to jquery:

```
function storeNotificationMessage(name) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        data: { 
            entry: $('#id').val(), 
            name: name, 
            msg: $('textarea#' + name).val() 
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: '?url=updateEntry',
        success: function(response) {
            done();
        }
    });
}
```

Remark: using AJAX with `async = false` makes very little sense and should be avoided.